# Парсинг сложного выражения, Регулярное выражение c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть выражение `{{я|ты}, он|она}, привет` нужно из фигурных скобок выбрать только 1 выражение разделенное `|`, чтоб получилось : `я, она, привет` или просто `привет` или `ты, он, привет` и тп

Сделал какт так :

```
var RegexPattern = @"\{([\s\S^\{]*?)\}";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(message, RegexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Random rnd = new Random();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var masstemp = match.Value.Split('|');
    var temp = masstemp[rnd.Next(0, masstemp.Count())];

    message = message.Replace(match.Value, temp);
}
return message.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
```

Но такое работает для простой строки, например `{ya|on}, qq` , в результате будет, например : `on, qq`. А вот с более сложной строкой `{{я|ты}, он|она}, привет` находит только `{{я|ты}` и рандомит от туда. Можете помочь исправить ? Если не особо понятно объяснил, то попробую по другому

Comment: А Вам точно регулярные выражения нужны? Может выбор вставляемых выражений организовать через логику приложения и вставлять только то, что нужно на место фигурных скобок?

Comment: @foxhound а можно пример ? ибо не особо понял, что вы имели в виду. А почему рег выражения не подходят ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004465/spintax-c-sharp-how-can-i-handle-this

Comment: @maxwell спасибо

Comment: Для разбора рекурсивных языков регулярки практически всегда являются неподходящим инструментом.

Comment: @VladD я так понимаю, вы имеете ввиду построение АСТ или что то типа него? А оно тут надо? Задача вроде простая, требований по скорости\памяти не выставлялись, не вижу смысла писать тут парсеры\разборы

Comment: @tym32167: Ага, разбор в смысле книги Дракона. Ну как бы да, можно и делать проще, но подобные задачи обычно обобщаются (добавим другую операцию, добавим escape-символ, введём подстановки, заигнорируем пробелы и переводы строк, добавим комментарии, ...), и наивный разбор довольно скоро перестаёт работать (либо становится несопровождаемой горой кода, пытающегося охватить все возможные случаи). Я в таких случаях предпочитаю решение «на вырост».

Comment: @VladD Да бросьте, это даже на синтаксис не похоже. Когда я в крайний раз делал подобное - то был простейший шаблонизатор абсолютно без выкидонов. К тому же мой вариант сейчас - это 10 строчек кода. А сколько займет разбор? И что если никаких доп фишек не понадобится? Мое мнение - пока не надо ничего серьезного - ничего серьезного нет смысла имплементить. Если только понадобится навернуть синтаксис, 10 строчек выкинуть будет не жалко. П.С. если осилили книгу Дракона - респект, я пока не смог :)

Comment: @tym32167: На первой работе писал компилятор, пришлось осилить (почти полностью) :-\ Я вот помню, как писал псевдоязык для тестовых скриптов, для которого сначала написал наивный парсер (один символ команды, остальное аргумент до конца строки), но требования разрастались, и пришлось ваять настоящий интерпретатор. Может быть, это заставляет меня видеть в каждой задаче парсер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Состряпал не самый оптимальный алгоритм, но работающий

Пишем функцию, которая заменит 1 выражение в скобках (без вложенных скобок)

```
Regex regex = new Regex("{([^{^}]+)}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
Random rand = new Random();

string Replace(string str)
{
    var match = regex.Match(str);
    if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count == 2)
    {
        var options = match.Groups[1].Value.Split(new[] {"|"} 
                , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var ind = rand.Next(2);
        return str.Replace(match.Value, options[ind]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Теперь строку на входе можно дергать,пока в ней не кончатся фигурные скобки

```
string GenerateString()
{
    var str = "{{я|ты}, он|она}, привет";

    while (str.Contains("{"))
        str = Replace(str);

    return str;
}
```

Занятно, что же получится, если запустить генерацию 1000 раз?

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(x=>GenerateString())
    .Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

На выходе будет

> она, привет
>
> ты, он, привет
>
> я, он, привет

Это все возможные значения, которые можно получить из вашего примера по вашим условиям.

**UPD** Почему нет `он, привет`

1. Берем начальную строку `{{я|ты}, он|она}, привет`
2. У нас есть выбор `я|ты`, выберем `я`, получим `{я, он|она}, привет`
3. Из `{я, он|она}, привет` есть выбор между `я, он` и `она`, выберем `я, он`, получим `я, он, привет`

Потому `он`  может идти только после `я` или `ты`. Если это не то, что вам надо, то вам следует пересмотреть условия.

Comment: а почему нету : `он, привет` и `я, она , привет` и `ты, она, привет` ? ведь для `он` есть ?

Comment: @Lolidze добавил апдейтом

Comment: да, спасибо. Я сам свою конструкцию не до конца понял :))

Comment: @Lolidze, в таком случае вам нужен шаблон `{я|ты}, {он|она}, привет`